# how to remove white gap around an image (bootstrap card)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```html
<div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center">Add To Cart In PHP</h1>
        <div class="row">
                <?php 
                $sql="select * from products";
                $res=$con->query($sql);
                if($res->num_rows>0)
                {
                    while($row=$res->fetch_assoc())
                    {
                        echo '
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 col-md-6 text-center">
                            <div class="card mb-4">
                                <a href="view.php?id='. $row['PID'] .'">
                                    <img class="card-img-top" src="assets/images/'. $row['PIC'] .'" alt=""> 
                                </a>
                                <div class="card-body">                     
                                    <a href="view.php?id='. $row['PID'] .'">
                                        <h5 class="card-title">'. $row['PNAME'] .'</h5>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        ';
                    }
                }
                ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhb1X.png)

If you look close at the above image, you can see the white gap at left side of the image card.  How do you clear that?  Is there any css or bootstrap code to clear the white gap?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code, it should solve the problem:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2 col-md-offset-3"><img src="assets/images/'. $row['PIC'] 
.'" alt=""></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2"><img src="assets/images/'. $row['PIC'] .'" alt="""> 
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2"><img src="assets/images/'. $row['PIC'] .'" alt=""> 
</div>
```